JetEngine Pagination stuck on first "current" page visally
I'm having trouble with [Crocoblock] JetEngine pagination (just noticed). Clicking pagination tied to listing grid (with query ID) has been working great so far. Now, it's letting me navigate via pagination but the visuals are messed up. When you are on page 4 it still shows current as page 1.
Anyone able to help sort this?
Tried turning off and on the plugin, tried rolling back the version. Also tried putting a widget in from scratch. Nothing works.
